# Finding minimal maximum share

Tags: prolog, minimum, mms, maximize

Recently I came across this question:
[Finding maximal minimum value set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63928475/finding-maximal-minimum-value-set)

And the code answer to compute the maximal minimum:

```
maximin(Elements, N, Maximin, LDistribution):-
  sumlist(Elements, Sum),
  TargetMaximin is -Sum//N,
  once(
  (
    between(TargetMaximin, -1, NMaximin),
    Maximin is -NMaximin,
    distribute(Elements, [], n, Maximin, N, 0, [], LDistributionOnce)
  )),
  LDistribution=LDistributionOnce.
  
distribute([], [], _, _, 0, _, _, []).
distribute(Elements, Skipped, y, Maximin, N, Cur, Distribution, [Distribution|LDistribution]):-
  N>0,
  Cur >= Maximin,
  succ(N1, N),
  append(Elements, Skipped, NElements),
  distribute(NElements, [], n, Maximin, N1, 0, [], LDistribution).
distribute([Element|Elements], Skipped, _, Maximin, N, Cur, Distribution, LDistribution):-
  N>0,
  NCur is Cur+Element,
  distribute(Elements, Skipped, y, Maximin, N, NCur, [Element|Distribution], LDistribution).
distribute([Element|Elements], Skipped, _, Maximin, N, Cur, Distribution, LDistribution):-
  N>0,
  distribute(Elements, [Element|Skipped], n, Maximin, N, Cur, Distribution, LDistribution).
```

I am trying to take a look at a different problem. Instead of computing the maximal minimum share, I want to compute the minimal maximum share. I have attempted the following changes to adjust this code:

```
minimax(Elements, N, Minimax, LDistribution):-
  sumlist(Elements, Sum),
  TargetMinimax is Sum//N,
  once(
  (
    between(TargetMinimax, Sum , NMinimax),
    Minimax is 0+NMinimax,
    distribute_minimax(Elements, [], n, Minimax, N, 0, [], LDistributionOnce)
  )),
  LDistribution=LDistributionOnce.
```

This means the search for a minimal maximum value will begin with approximately the sum divided by the amount of people. Addiotionally, I changed the distribution function:

```
distribute_minimax([], [], _, _, 0, _, _, []).
distribute_minimax(Elements, Skipped, y, Minimax, N, Cur, Distribution, [Distribution|LDistribution]):-
                                   N>0, Cur =< Minimax, succ(N1, N), append(Elements, Skipped, NElements)
                                   , distribute_minimax(NElements, [], n, Minimax, N1, 0, [], LDistribution).
distribute_minimax([Element|Elements], Skipped, _, Minimax, N, Cur, Distribution, LDistribution):-
                                   N>0, NCur is Cur+Element
                                   , distribute_minimax(Elements, Skipped, y, Minimax, N, NCur, [Element|Distribution], LDistribution).
```

But the problem is that my program doesn't know how to skip on items, and then use them later, so I get wrong answers. Any advice?

Comment: The "skip on items and use them later" is done in the related linked answer by accumulating skipped Elements in Skipped, and then appending them to Elements when a group is formed. So that solution has sort of two recursions embedded in the same procedure. One fits elements in a group, the other builds all the groups and ensures all elements are used.

Comment: But skipping an item worked fine when we refereed to maximal-minimum, because it simply means more items, and as long as the value of the set is larger than X, its ok. Yet here, we want the value to be smaller than X. So skipping items without considering their values is a bit tricky.

Comment: I see it this way: eventually all items have to be added to exactly one group. So when you skip an item then you will have to use it in another group. The fouth clause in my solution skips an item and adds to the Skipped list. The second clause which "closes" a group adds the skipped items to the list of Elements so those skipped items are again part of the Elements to use in further groups